# Getting Admin Auth Token

Tags: magento2, api, login, token

I'm new to Magento 2 software and trying to get some help to my scenario. One of our integration were failing to connect to our store API calls stating the expected response was json but getting HTML.

I tried to to invoke the API from postman to see whether the username and password used are able to get a auth token. API call was successful with the status code 200 however the return was HTML content instead of the auth token. When I checked the HTML content it's nothing but our admin login page.  I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Any help / inputs is really appreciated.

I used the URI https:///admin/rest/V1/integration/admin/token?username=MyAdminUser&password=Password123 to get the auth token.

Comment: Can you send the Postman screenshot here?

Comment: Thanks Rinto. I figured out the problem myself. We have a custom path so API link was incorrect. After changing it, it all worked fine.